# How to query and filter my data in web form by using LIKE and %% operators?

Tags: c#

I want to filter and select data from sql server in my web form by using LIKE and % % operator

I searched in stackoverflow solutions but i cannot find the solution to my case and i tried alot but its not working correctly. This is my code:

```
protected void BtnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string sql = @" SELECT [appt_id],visitor_name,mobile ,work_place.work_place_name as work_place_name,days.day as day,date,[time],[subject],[duration],appointment_place.appt_place as appt_place 
                               FROM [Appointments] 
                               inner join days on days.day_id = Appointments.day_id 
                               inner join appointment_place on appointment_place.appt_place_id =Appointments.appt_place_id
                               inner join work_place on work_place.work_place_id = Appointments.work_place_id 
                               where 1=1 ";

                string condition = "";
                string orderby = "order by date";
                // orderby += "order by appointments.time";

                if (txtVisitorName.Text != "")
                {
                    condition += " and appointments.visitor_name like '" + txtVisitorName.Text + "'";
                }
                if (txtsubject.Text != "")
                {
                    condition += " and appointments.subject like '" + txtsubject.Text + "'";
                }
                if (txtMobileNo.Text != "")
                {
                    condition += " and appointments.mobile ='" + txtMobileNo.Text + "'";
                }


                DataTable dt = func.fireDatatable(string.Format(sql + condition + orderby));
                gvappt.DataSource = dt;
                gvappt.DataBind();
            }
```

I expect the output of code to use LIKE and %% to search visitors name or subject contains part of name or part of subject ?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the `DataTable dt = ...` line and output `sql + condition + orderby` into the Immediate Window, you will see that you are missing the `WHERE` clause from your condition text. It would be very obvious had you debugged your program.

Comment: another sql injectable site.

Comment: You will also need to add in those `%` around your textbox values when concatenating those values into your sql string. Again, inspecting the final SQL you are sending to your database and even trying to execute in a seperate client would make this pretty simple to troubleshoot. Ultimately though you should be parameterizing your sql otherwise someone could search for "subject" of `';DROP TABLE appointments; --` and you will be in a world of hurt.

Comment: I think you are missing a WHERE clause.

Comment: I added where 1=1 see edit , and its same not filtering data when i search by part of the subject name its show the message no data found but when i search by complete name or subject it show data

Comment: @JNevill yes this is what i need where to put  %   %  before and after the code condition += " and appointments.subject like %'" + txtsubject.Text + "'%";   i tried this but its not filtering .

Comment: @Abdullah Debug your code and pull out the finished SQL string from string.Format(sql + condition + orderby). Run that on its own and work backwards from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the correct answer to my question :

```
if (txtDocSubject.Text != "")
    {
    condition +=" and Documents.Document_subject like '%"+txtDocSubject.Text+"%'";
    }
```